# Why does CouchDb-python (or do I) confuse strings and dictionaries?

Tags: python, couchdb, couchdb-python

I'm trying to use the Python wrapper for CouchDB to update a database. The file is structured as a nested dictionary as follows.

```
doc = { ...,
   'RLSoo': {'RT_freq': 2, 'tweet': "They're going to play monopoly now. 
     This makes me feel like an excellent mother. #Sandy #NYC"}, 
    'GiltCityNYC': {},
  ....}
```

I would like to put each entry of the larger dicitionary, for example `RLSoo` into its own document. However, I get an error message when I try the following code.

```
 for key in doc:
      db.update(doc[key],all_or_nothing=True)
```

**Error Message**

```
TypeError: expected dict, got <type 'str'>
```

I don't understand why CouchDB won't accept the dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According [`Database.update()`](http://code.google.com/p/couchdb-python/source/browse/couchdb/client.py#714) method realization and his documentation, first argument should be list of document objects (e.g. list of dicts). Since you `doc` variable has dict type, direct iteration over it actually iterates over all his keys which are string typed. If I understood your case right, probably your `doc` contains nested documents as [values](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values). So, try just:

```
db.update(doc.values(), all_or_nothing=True)
```

And it all first level values are dicts, it should works!